# Showing $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathcal{U}(R))\cong \operatorname{Hom}(R(G),R).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a group $G$ which is a module over a unitary  commutative ring $R$, we set $R(G)$ to be a group ring and $\mathcal{U}(R)$ the group of unit of $R$.

> I'm trying to show that:
>   $$\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathcal{U}(R))\cong \operatorname{Hom}(R(G),R),$$ 
>   where the first hom is to be intended between groups and the second one with rings.

An idea that I had was to take a general homomorphism $f:G\to\mathcal{U}(R)$ and set $\bar{f}:R(G)\to R$ defined as $$\bar{f}(\sum_{g\in G}r_{g}g):=\sum_{g\in G}r_{g}f(g)$$
and so I'd like to prove $\varphi(f):=\bar{f}$ to be the isomorphism sought.

Unfortunatly, I wasn't able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a homomorphism $h:R(G)\to R$, note that $h(g)\in \mathcal{U}(R)$ since 
$$h(g)h(g^{-1})=h(gg^{-1})=h(1_G)=1_R$$
and, similarly $h(g^{-1})h(g)=1_R$, so $h(g^{-1})=h(g)^{-1}$. Define $\bar{h}:G\to \mathcal{U}(R)$ by $\bar{h}(g)=h(g)$ and check that the assignment $\psi(h)=\bar{h}$ is the inverse of the map $\varphi$ you defined.